# Python - How to stimulate mouse click without moving cursor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, click, pyautogui

I'm trying to use `pyautogui` and click at a certain area on my screen, but I want it to click without physically moving my cursor, kind of like an invisible click. So far, I have no idea how to do it, only the typical automate clicking and moving of cursor position to the area.

I used the following:

```
pyautogui.click(x=100, y=13)
```

But, it moved the cursor to that specific position instead of sending click. Is there any possible way to do so with pyautogui or any other module ?

Answer (score 0):

This usually works on the primary monitor. I tested with the right click.

```
import pyautogui

# Get the size of the primary monitor.
screenWidth, screenHeight = pyautogui.size() 
print(screenWidth, screenHeight)

pyautogui.click(100, 200, button='right')
```

Comment: didn't work, it moves the cursor at that point and then clicks it.